# How do I inherit from default Android style in my custom styles.xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview, android-styles

I am currently using this custom styles layout for my `EditTexts` defined in 'styles.xml':

```
<style name="Form_EditView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/large_text_size</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/pink</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/pink</item>
</style>
```

However now my dilemma occurs as I have a `TextView` that I would like to be styled like a default Android EditText but then to also apply my above custom styling. The default Android style is the one displayed below:

```
style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"
```

I know that inheritance is possible in layout styles files but how do I go about inheriting from Android default styles in my custom styles, to achieve something similar to this:

```
<style name="Widget.EditText.Form_EditView">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to inherit some other style - is to use `parent` attribute:

```
<style name="Form_EditView" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
```

As @Bobby StJacques pointed out, if you want to inherit styles **you defined** (not built-in Android ones), you can use the following form:

```
<style name="Form_EditView.SomeCustomizedEditView">
    ....
</style>
```

In this case you inherit your already defined `Form_EditView`

Comment: In fact, this is the ONLY way if you are inheriting from a style in another package.  If they are in the same package, you can use dot notation (which is arguably simpler).