# How to align a button in Relative Layout Programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

[image: Code that i have tried for aligning the button to right of the Relative Layout]

I am trying to align a Button in a Relative Layout programmatically but the app is crashing every time i run with the above code. What am i doing wrong? I am facing the same problem with LayoutParams when i am trying to use margins.

Logcat

[image: Logcat]

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="e.user.customcomponent.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/rLayout">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/EditText" />
    <e.user.customcomponent.UIButton
        style="@style/UIButtonStyle.Action.Data" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

button_style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="UIButtonStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:tag">UIButton</item>
        <item name="android:id">@id/UIButton</item>
        <item name="android:layout_below">@id/EditText</item>
        <item name="SetText">Save Data</item>
        <item name="SetRoundCorners">true</item>

        <item name="SetAlignCentre">true</item>

    </style>

    <item name="UIButton" type="id">UIButton</item>

</resources>
```

**Added UIButton.java File**

UIButton.java

```
package e.user.customcomponent;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UIButton extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton {

    Button btn = findViewWithTag("UIButton");
    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.et);
    DatabaseHandler db;
    SQLiteDatabase datab;
    final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    public UIButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    public UIButton(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.UIButton);
        int count = typedArray.getIndexCount();
        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {

                int attr = typedArray.getIndex(i);
                // the attr corresponds to the title attribute
                if (attr == R.styleable.UIButton_SetText) {
                    String msg = typedArray.getString(attr);
                    btn.setText(msg);
                } else if(attr == R.styleable.UIButton_SetSubmitAction) {
                    boolean action = typedArray.getBoolean(attr,false);
                    if(action == true) {
                        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Button Clicked!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                } else if (attr == R.styleable.UIButton_SetRoundCorners) {
                    boolean roundCorners = typedArray.getBoolean(attr,false);
                    if(roundCorners == true) {
                        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corners);
                        GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) btn.getBackground();
                        drawable.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    }
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.UIButton_SaveData) {
                    boolean saveData = typedArray.getBoolean(attr,false);
                    if(saveData == true) {
                        db = new DatabaseHandler(context,"DemoDB",null,1);
                        datab = db.getWritableDatabase();
                        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                cv.put("data",editText.getText().toString());

                                long id = datab.insert("demoTable",null,cv);

                                Toast.makeText(context,String.valueOf(id)+"Data Inserted!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else if (attr == R.styleable.UIButton_SetAlignCentre) {
                    boolean setAlignCentre = typedArray.getBoolean(attr,false);
                    if(setAlignCen
                    tre == true) {
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) btn.getLayoutParams();
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                        btn.setLayoutParams(params);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            typedArray.recycle();
        }
    }

    public UIButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

System cant find your custom UTButton class thats why its throwing exception make sure that you have declared proper package while using that view

Comment: But if i remove the code for aligning there wont be any error the app runs successfully @HarshPatel

Answer (score 0):

This xml coading is causing problem-:

```
<e.user.customcomponent.UIButton
            style="@style/UIButtonStyle.Action.Data" />
```

Check you are using same package name as that you have declared.

Comment: UIButtonStyle is one xml file which contains all design attributes of the Button, Action is one xml file which contains all action attributes and Data which contains all data attributes. So i am Inheriting all three xml like mentioned in this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34004742/7494466

Answer (score 0):

May be your button is not bound, so it caused the attempt to invoke the virtual method. Try to output what the current btn is null

Comment: But it works for the other functions perfectly if i remove the align code. @Autumn

Comment: This may be because he is bound after alignment, so that it fits perfectly into other functions, you need to print out before aligning to see if he is null, and it's best to provide the full UIButton code, Used to solve the problem

Comment: btn has just been created and is not added to the view, so getLayoutParams () is null.

Comment: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    , ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
btn.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: Now the app runs without any errors but the property align is not being reflected in the app this is what i have done

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
btn.setLayoutParams(params);